# How to set for loop correctly to show 1 image per side

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, uiview, uiimageview

[this is what happens and i do not want](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOe7EP4DD3yOGV5UFFCTmdnMzczWThYcW1UVnVPdEgtS2E0/view?usp=sharing)

[this is what i want but it only works for my last UIImage view and after i flip once](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOe7EP4DD3yamhlaU84Tnc1VFczWHRySHhWeGhzUEllSExN/view?usp=sharing)

I have a program that loops through 5 images.  I'm trying to get only show the regular images on the front side of each imageView and the TextImages on the back of each imageView. Instead, it's showing both images on both sides of each imageView. The last card works just like its suppose to after you flip the card once by tapping the view. I'm sure it has something to do with my for loop that I'm not writing correctly.

Any help would be amazing. Thank you in advance!!!

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Project_BC
//
//  Created by Amen Parham on 7/5/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Amen Parham. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var open: UIBarButtonItem!
    var myImageArray = [UIImage]()
    var myImageArray2 = [UIImage]()

    var front = UIImageView()
    var back = UIImageView()

    var showingFront = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapped))
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        mainScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
        mainScrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        mainScrollView.frame = view.frame
        myImageArray = [img1, img2 ,img3, img4, img5]
        myImageArray2 = [textImg1, textImg2 ,textImg3, textImg4, textImg5]

        for i in 0..<myImageArray.count {

            front = UIImageView()
            front.image = myImageArray[i]
            front.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            let yPosition = self.view.frame.height * CGFloat(i) + self.view.frame.height/2 - (self.view.frame.height / 1.1)/2
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width/2 - (self.view.frame.width / 1.1)/2
            front.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: self.view.frame.width / 1.1, height: self.view.frame.height / 1.1)
            front.layer.borderWidth = 5

            back = UIImageView()
            back.image = myImageArray2[i]
            back.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            back.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: self.view.frame.width / 1.1, height: self.view.frame.height / 1.1)
            back.layer.borderWidth = 5

            mainScrollView.contentSize.height = mainScrollView.frame.height * CGFloat(i + 1)
            mainScrollView.addSubview(front)
            mainScrollView.addSubview(back)
        }
    }

    func tapped() {
        if (showingFront) {
            UIView.transition(from: front, to: back, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
            showingFront = false
        } else {
            UIView.transition(from: back, to: front, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
            showingFront = true
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because you are using the same `xPosition` and `yPosition` for both your `imageView`s. Have you tried giving them different values?

Comment: Why the links to something requiring login? Very bad.

Comment: yeah i tried so but their positions need to be the same.  Just the flipping animation effect is what i think is the issue :/ - Malik

Comment: You were attaching the image from your email, guy. How can we access it?

Comment: Let me check, my apologize @t4nhpt

Comment: Go ahead and try the videos out :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, you have two class-level variables named `front` and `back`, and then, in your `for loop`, you assigned it 5 times, but just the last value is kept. So that is the reason.

How to fix: I think in your `tapped` method, you should have an index of current image position, so that it will access to right view to play the flipping animation.

---

Just see the video you attached. IMO, in this case, we should use `UITableView`, should not manually add each item to UIScrollView. Then we will handle the `didSelectItemAddIndex` event to play flipping animation.

Comment: not sure if I'm following you.  Are you suggesting I start my second for loop off where my first for loop ended?  Are you able to share a piece of code?

Comment: See my edit about `UITableView`. You know how to implement `UITableView`, right?

Comment: Okay, I will look into that